# Sign in with Twitter button functionality is not working in Twitter api version 1.1

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, twitter-anywhere

Sign in with Twitter button functionality is not working in Twitter api version 1.1.         Is there any solution with  twitter @anywhere api in 1.1 version.

https://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=<%=TwiterAPI %>&v=1

This is not working in twitter api version 1.1.How we can use this in new version to render the sign in button of twitter

Answer (score 3):

Twitter Anywhere was [discontinued](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/sunsetting-anywhere) in March and is effectively removed since the shutdown of API version 1.0. To allow signing in with Twitter now, follow this manual: [Implementing Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter).

Comment: The second link is no longer working.  Check [Log in with Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/login-in-with-twitter)